# jquery maxlength and minlength not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation but validation for `maxlength` and `minlength` is not working properly.

```
function form_validate(){
    var validator=$("#cheque_pickup").validate({
    rules: {
        "pick[pin_code]": {
           required:true,
           digits:true,
           maxlength: 6,
           minlength:6
        }
    }
    });
}

<form onsubmit="form_validate();">
    <input type="text" name="pick[pin_code]" id="pin_code" placeholder="" value=""  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need inline JavaScript to call any function.**  The plugin will automatically capture the submit action.  In fact, you don't need the `form_validate()` function at all.  That's what the `submitHandler` callback option will already do for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cheque_pickup").validate({
        rules: {
            "pick[pin_code]": {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                // maxlength: 6,    // <- can use 'rangelength' instead
                // minlength: 6     // <- can use 'rangelength' instead
                rangelength: [6,6]  // <- one method will replace two
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax or form submit here
            // alert('form is valid');
            return false;
        }
    });
});

<form id="cheque_pickup">
    <input type="text" name="pick[pin_code]" id="pin_code" placeholder="" value=""  />
</form>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/RHHe5/**

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#cheque_pickup").validate({
        rules: {
            "pick[pin_code]": {
               required:true,
               digits:true,
               maxlength: 6,
               minlength:6
            }
        }
    });
    });

   function form_validate(){
    if($("#cheque_pickup").valid())
    {
        //post form here
    }

    }
```

Comment: You don't need inline JavaScript to call any function.  The plugin will automatically capture the submit action.  In fact, you don't need the `form_validate()` function at all.  That's what the `submitHandler` callback option will already do for you.